# Authentication/access control in CORBA

Tags: java, authentication, interceptor, corba

I'm writing an application that gives access to some imaginary laboratory with various devices. I use Java with CORBA. The problem is that many users can simultaneously try to access those devices. Only one should get it and actively use, while other users can only be notified about changing state of devices. 
It would be easy to implement if only I have a way to identify who calls a method on a device. If it is a caller who previously obtained that device, he would do whatever he want. If it is other user then I would throw an appropriate exception on illegal method call.

How to obtain caller identity?
How to implement the auth logic, so it would be independent of business(laboratory :P) logic? Does CORBA has something like 'interceptors' or something like these?

I'm really counting on you fellow StackOverflowers :) I'm quite short of time to implement it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. CORBA has interceptors and yes, you can use them. They are not really independent of your business logic, but the business logic does not rely on authentication and authorization.

The bad news is that there is no simple way to implement this.

The interceptor logic depends on your implementation of CORBA. You wrote, you've implemented it in Java, but left open which CORBA implementation you used. This could be the SUN/Oracle-with-Java-shipped-ORB, JacORB, Bea Weblogic and others.

A general introduction in CORBA Security could be found at:

- [Introduction in CORBA Security](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/security.html)
- [CORBASEC FAQ](http://cadse.cs.fiu.edu/corba/corbasec/faq/single-page/CORBASEC-FAQ.html)

If your provide more information about your ORB, helping more is possible...

Comment: Well, I was using CORBA packages shipped with JDK by default (org.omg.*). It's a partial CORBA impl, isn't it? 
Nevertheless it was an academic project and get a passing grade. It's possible that it was my first and last CORBA project..

Comment: @Paweł CORBA has had its time. But nowadays you'd use other techniques. Nevertheless CORBA works fine and is industry proven ;)